# Choice of editor when running under sudo

Tags: sudo, environment-variables, editors

On an Ubuntu 12.04 machine I've used the alternatives system to set the **editor** to **vim.basic**. I get the correct editor when root but not when I sudo to root and run crontab, and I'm trying to understand why.

A bit more detail. The alternative **editor** is currently set to **vim.basic** by manual mode (output trimmed):

```
% sudo update-alternatives --set editor /usr/bin/vim.basic
% update-alternatives --display editor
editor - manual mode
  link currently points to /usr/bin/vim.basic
/bin/nano - priority 40
  slave editor.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/nano.1.gz
/usr/bin/vim.basic - priority 30
  slave editor.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/vim.1.gz
  slave editor.fr.1.gz: /usr/share/man/fr/man1/vim.1.gz
  slave editor.it.1.gz: /usr/share/man/it/man1/vim.1.gz
  slave editor.pl.1.gz: /usr/share/man/pl/man1/vim.1.gz
  slave editor.ru.1.gz: /usr/share/man/ru/man1/vim.1.gz
Current 'best' version is '/bin/nano'.
```

If I sudo to root and edit crontab the editor is vim.basic:

```
% sudo -i
% crontab -e
# editor is vim; :help shows
# *help.txt*      For Vim version 7.3.  Last change: 2010 Jul 20
```

EDITOR and SHELL as root:

```
# env | grep -i editor
EDITOR=vim
# echo $0
-bash
```

However as a normal user if I sudo crontab the editor is nano:

```
% sudo crontab -e
# GNU nano 2.2.6
```

EDITOR and SHELL as normal user:

```
% env | grep -i editor
EDITOR=vim
% echo $0
zsh
```

Now I'm noticing that **nano** has a higher priority (40) than **vim.basic** (30), so I could change the priority of vim.basic. But that defeats the purpose of **manual mode**.

**Update**

I've noticed that using **sudo -E** gives the correct editor, implying problem is environment related. That is:

```
sudo crontab -e     # nano editor is used
sudo -E crontab -e  # vim editor is used
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `VISUAL`?

Comment: @MadHatter could be right, try EXPORT EDITOR=vim & EXPORT VISUAL=vim

Comment: Thanks @madhatter I'll give that a go. Although EDITOR is already set...

Answer (score 4):

In most configurations, sudo strips most environment variables. You can see the sudo configuration by running `sudo -V` as root (so `sudo sudo -V` as a user with sudo permissions).

On Ubuntu, variables are stripped except from a small list, and `EDITOR` and `VISUAL` are not in the list to preserve. So when you run `sudo somecommand`, your per-user editor preferences are not applied when running `somecommand`.

When you run `sudo -E`, the file is copied to a temporary location, then sudo runs your editor with no additional privileges, and finally the temporary file is moved to the final location if the editor returns a success status. Since the editor is executed without additional privileges, sudo doesn't strip the environment.

You should use `sudo -E` whenever possible, since this lets you run your favorite editor without concerns about running programs with elevated privileges. When this isn't possible (for example, to run `crontab -e`, you can choose your editor by defining your preference again inside the command executed by sudo:

```
sudo env VISUAL=vim crontab -e
```

Comment: Thanks @Gilles. But even with EDITOR and VISUAL stripped, /usr/bin/editor is set to vim.basic by alternatives, so it should be used instead of nano. More investigation required on my part...

Comment: @SoniaHamilton Hence my last command, which sets the `VISUAL` variable again after it's stripped.

Comment: Thanks @Gilles. But what's the purpose of alternatives and /usr/bin/editor then? They seem redundant. Or maybe it's up to each program to look at /usr/bin/editor, and VISUAL/EDITOR are the older, more established mechanisms?

Comment: @SoniaHamilton Alternatives and `/usr/bin/editor` are for a system-wide default. The `EDITOR` and `VISUAL` environment variables are for per-user defaults.